# Angular Checkbox Alternate

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

Simple problem: Two checkboxes; Both starting NOT checked; Clicking either one enables and checks while making sure the other is not checked.

```
<div data-ng-init="indicator=false;decision=false">
<input type="checkbox" name="aName" data-ng-click="indicator=!indicator;decision=true" data-ng-checked="indicator && decision"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="aName" data-ng-click="indicator=!indicator;decision=true" data-ng-checked="!indicator && decision"/>
</div>
```

Current result is both start out checked: https://jsfiddle.net/u22a5wz9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div >
    {{checkBox}}<br>
    Above 1.3v
    <input type="checkbox" name="aName" ng-model="checkBox" ng-true-value="{value:'one'}"/>One
    <input type="checkbox" name="aName" ng-model="checkBox" ng-true-value="{value:'two'}"/>Two<br>
    
    Below 1.3v
    <input type="checkbox" name="aName" ng-model="checkBox" ng-true-value="one"/>One
    <input type="checkbox" name="aName" ng-model="checkBox" ng-true-value="two"/>Two<br>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good but as of Angular v1.3.x ngTrueValue expects an expression.

Comment: this works, except the value needs to be boolean; which ultimately leads me back to the false checkbox starting off checked. But this gets me closer to what I was looking for, so I think I go with this and just make a work around. Thx

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div >
    {{checkBox}}<br>
    Above 1.3v
    <input type="checkbox" name="aName" ng-model="checkBox" ng-true-value="{value:'one'}"/>One
    <input type="checkbox" name="aName" ng-model="checkBox" ng-true-value="{value:'two'}"/>Two<br>
    
    Below 1.3v
    <input type="checkbox" name="aName" ng-model="checkBox" ng-true-value="one"/>One
    <input type="checkbox" name="aName" ng-model="checkBox" ng-true-value="two"/>Two<br>
    
  </div>
</div>
```